Is there a Rate Limit with FTP?
I'm coding a Chat-App right now that uses a Txt-File at a FTP Server for the chatlog. My question is, if FTP has a rate limit? Because I want to update the Chatlog as fast as possible in the client-side but if I send a ftp connection that fast all the time would the client get rate limited by the ftp-server? Is this question more based on how the FTP-Server is configured? Cause I am sending every second one connection right now, would I be able to send connections faster? Like 500ms?

Isn't that chatlog getting bigger all the time, which will cause greater and greater delays as time goes by? In other words, maybe there are other solutions to send only updates
